# Retrieve a variable number of subsets with different conditions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS city (
    id  serial primary key,
    name    character varying UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inhabitants (
    id  serial primary key,
    fullname    character varying UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    home    integer REFERENCES city
);

INSERT INTO city (name) VALUES
('michigan'),
('washington'),
('new york'),
('london'),
('los angeles')
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO inhabitants (fullname, home) VALUES
('flannigan, amy', 1),
('hannigan, leon', 1),
('shennanigan, frank', 1),
('catcher, floyd', 2),
('rice, amy', 2),
('black, joe', 2),
('higgins, simon', 3),
('stewart, rick', 3),
('white, frank', 3),
('henson, ben', 5),
('hedge, tim', 5),
('wilson, bill', 5),
('moriarty, doc', 4),
('fletcher, dolores', 4),
('fletcher, hank', 4),
('williamson, ann', 1),
('stewart, mary', 3)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

I want to extract a varying number of subsets with a varying number of inhabitants for each subset. Currently I am using a query for each subset, e.g., if I need two subsets I may use these two queries:

```
select fullname, home from inhabitants i
where home = (SELECT id FROM city WHERE name = 'michigan')
ORDER BY random() LIMIT 2;
```

and

```
select fullname, home from inhabitants i
where home = (SELECT id FROM city WHERE name = 'london')
ORDER BY random() LIMIT 1;
```

The results may look like this:

```
    fullname     | home 
-----------------+------
 hannigan, leon  |    1
 williamson, ann |    1
(2 rows)
```

and

```
     fullname      | home 
-------------------+------
 fletcher, dolores |    4
(1 row)
```

I join those two results in Bash, so they look what I actually want:

```
    fullname       | home 
-------------------+------
 hannigan, leon    |    1
 williamson, ann   |    1
 fletcher, dolores |    4
(3 rows)
```

I would like to minimize the number of database calls.

Is there a way to do this with one query (or function) or at least a better way than what I am doing currently?

Comment: Not really related to your code, but you realize Michigan and Washington aren't cities, right?  Washington, D.C. would be a city, but Michigan is most definitely a state.

Comment: @Steve-o169 You do realize that this is just a dumb example and not a geography contest, right?

Comment: @Steve-o169 This example was derived from a far more complex database with more complex queries. The main focus of this example is to simplify the database while still keeping it accurate enough to represent the problem. So when I extracted some sample data I typed 
"Wasington" for brevity instead of "Washington, D.C." without checking for ambiguities. Same for "Michigan" because the content does not affect the logic at all.
This requires a certain capability of abstract thought which you apparently have not yet fully developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select fullname, home 
from (select i.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by home order by random()) as seqnum
      from inhabitants i
     ) i join
     city c
     on c.id = i.home
where (name = 'michigan' and seqnum <= 2) or
      (name = 'london' and seqnum <= 1)
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that it extracts exactly two subsets. The number of subsets can vary, though, i.e., there may be a third, fourth etc. `or` needed in the `where` clause.

Comment: @nautical . . . So modify the `where` clause to get what you need.  Your question is about two specific cities, but the query is pretty obviously generalizable.

Comment: Sorry, this may be obious to you, but I only do sql every once in a while. I can put the above query in a function like `create function testfun(VARIADIC varchar[]) ... where name = ANY($1);` and call it with a varying number of arguments: `select * from testfun('michigan','london','los angeles');`. However, this returns all entries which match the cities. I do not know how to work in the limits. The only way I can think of, currently, is by string concatenation inside a script. Eventually, I just want to call my script with the citiy,limit pairs and have the query execute automatically.

Comment: @nautical . . . This question is about constructing a query, and it has been answered.  If you have *another* question about constructing a function with a particular type of arguments, then ask another question.